# Getting error while building docker image in Jenkins

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

Getting error while building docker image in Jenkins. I am using google lab CPO200 course.

```
/tmp/hudson7642004630213449625.sh: 2: 
/tmp/hudson7642004630213449625.sh: ./build.sh: Permission denied
```

Comment: `Permission denied` means you don't have enough permission to perform this. try to run using root privilege.

Comment: I am using Jenkins to build my image. I dont see any option to run as root.

Comment: Are you trying to build docker images inside a docker container? If so, you may need to run your container with privileged mode enabled.

Comment: I have marked up your error message, this is done by prefixing it with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `build.sh` has the execute bit?  Maybe `chmod +x`?

You can get a `permission denied` error if you try to execute a shell script that does not have the execute bit set.